# docker: mysql server stops directly after starting

Tags: mysql, docker

after starting the the mysql server within docker, it stops immediately. the docker log is not very meaningful ;) i've no idea, what's wrong. in my opinion i didn't changed anything.

```
mysql 15:04:45.27
mysql 15:04:45.29 Welcome to the Bitnami mysql container
mysql 15:04:45.30 Subscribe to project updates by watching https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-mysql
mysql 15:04:45.31 Submit issues and feature requests at https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-mysql/issues
mysql 15:04:45.31
mysql 15:04:45.32 INFO ==> ** Starting MySQL setup **
mysql 15:04:45.36 INFO ==> Validating settings in MYSQL_*/MARIADB_* env vars
mysql 15:04:45.37 INFO ==> Initializing mysql database
mysql 15:04:45.39 INFO ==> Updating 'my.cnf' with custom configuration
mysql 15:04:45.40 INFO ==> Setting user option
mysql 15:04:45.41 INFO ==> Using persisted data
mysql 15:04:45.45 INFO ==> Running mysql_upgrade
mysql 15:04:45.46 INFO ==> Starting mysql in background
mysql 15:04:47.96 INFO ==> Stopping mysql
```

the docker compose file:

```yml
---

# Docker Web Development Stack (dstack) 1.0.3
#
# Runs Apache, MySQL, PHP, Redis and PhpMyAdmin
# SSL is preconfigured.
# Imagemagick and XDebug are activated.
#
# Run with 
# docker-compose up -d
#
# (C)2020 Harald Schneider
#

version: "3"

services:

  # --- MySQL 5.7
  #
  mysql:
    container_name: "dev-mysql"
    image: bitnami/mysql:5.7
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=YOUR_PASSWORD_HERE
      - MYSQL_USER=admin
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=YOUR_PASSWORD_HERE
    ports:
      - '127.0.0.1:3306:3306'
    volumes:
      - ./mysql/data:/bitnami/mysql/data
  
  # --- PHP 7.4
  #
  php:
    container_name: "dev-php"
    image: bitnami/php-fpm:7.4
    depends_on:
      - redis
    volumes:
      - ../www:/app:delegated
      - ./php/php.ini:/opt/bitnami/php/etc/conf.d/php.ini:ro

  # --- Apache 2.4
  #
  apache:
    container_name: "dev-apache"
    image: bitnami/apache:2.4
    ports:
      - '80:8080'
      - '443:8443'
    depends_on:
      - php
    volumes:
      - ../www:/app:delegated
      - ./apache/my_vhost.conf:/vhosts/myapp.conf:ro
      - ./apache/my_httpd.conf:/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/httpd.conf
      - ./apache/certs:/certs
      # Use this for bitnami's builtin certs:
      # ./docker/apache/certs:/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/certs 

  # --- Redis 6.0
  #
  redis:
    container_name: "dev-redis"
    image: bitnami/redis:6.0
    environment:
      - REDIS_PASSWORD=YOUR_PASSWORD_HERE

  # --- PhpMyAdmin latest
  # Acccess via
  # http://127.0.0.1:81 or https://127.0.0.1:8143
  # Login with user root and mysql-password.
  #
  phpmyadmin:
    container_name: "dev-phpmyadmin"
    image: bitnami/phpmyadmin:latest
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    ports:
      - '81:8080'
      - '8143:8443'
    environment:
      - DATABASE_HOST=host.docker.internal

volumes:
  dev-mysql:
    driver: local
```

any hints how i get more log-information or any hints what exactly could cause the problem?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
environment:
  - BITNAMI_DEBUG=true
```

Answer (score -1):

"Solution": Funny - or not - the problem was/were "damaged" mysql database(s). But I had no chance to see any logs anywhere. Just had a guess, and I was right.

Comment: To see the logs, you can issue the command `docker container logs -f <container>`